# Multiply rows (with row names) in one data frame with matching column names in another

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Values=c(0.01,0.05), row.names=c("X", "Y"))
df1
  Values
X   0.01
Y   0.05

df2 <-data.frame(c(0,1,1), c(1,0,0), c(1,1,1))
colnames(df2) <- c("X","Y","Z")

df2
  X Y Z
1 0 1 1
2 1 0 1
3 1 0 1
```

I wish to perform a **rowwise** operation on df2, where I multiply every **column** in df2 with its **corresponding** row in df1 and then perform a **summation**.

For example, for row 1 of df2, I wish to calculate:

```
df2 %>% rowwise %>% mutate(newVAL=(df1["X",]*df2[1,"X"])+(df1["Y",]*df2[1,"Y"]))
```

while excluding columns that don't match (rows in df1) or have NAs.

I have several thousands of rows in df1 and several thousands of rows and columns in df2.

Any help is much appreciated!!

PS. I have implemented this in Perl using hashes and was using the system() call to perform these calculations within an Rmarkdown document. In order to keep it completely reproducible, I am trying to redo it in R. Happy to share the Perl code if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: For this particular case of element-wise multiplication and, then. summation, you could use `tcrossprod(as.matrix(df2[, rownames(df1)]), t(df1))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it looks like you need `sweep`.

```
df3 <- sweep(df2[, rownames(df1)], 2, t(df1), '*')
df3$total <- rowSums(df3)
```

Comment: Clever. A nice idea using the rownames to select columns by name.

Comment: Thank you both. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt in base R matching the rows to the columns between the two sets:

```
rowSums(
  sweep(df2,
        MARGIN=2,
        STATS=df1$Values[match(colnames(df2), rownames(df1))],
        FUN=`*`),
  na.rm=TRUE
)
#[1] 0.05 0.01 0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `rep` to make the lengths same to multiply and then get the `rowSums`.  It will be more efficient to use `rep` as it is faster

```
rowSums(df2[rownames(df1)] * rep(df1$Values, each = nrow(df2)))
#[1] 0.05 0.01 0.01
```

---

Or using the `tidyrverse` packages

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df2 %>% 
     select_(.dots = rownames(df1)) %>% 
     map2(df1$Values, `*`) %>%
     reduce(`+`)
#[1] 0.05 0.01 0.01
```

#### Update

If we need it as a column,

```
df2 %>% 
    select_(.dots = rownames(df1)) %>%
    map2(df1$Values, `*`) %>%
    reduce(`+`) %>%
    mutate(df2, total = .)
#  X Y Z total
#1 0 1 1  0.05
#2 1 0 1  0.01
#3 1 0 1  0.01
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to tie the summation of each row to df2 instead of returning a vector of values using tidyverse? Something similar to what @user127649 has suggested?

Comment: @cityofwisdom  Updated the answer