# Match row value in df1 with column name in df2 to return same row value of df2

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This question is similar to what I found here: [Multiply rows (with row names) in one data frame with matching column names in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708426/multiply-rows-with-row-names-in-one-data-frame-with-matching-column-names-in-a])

But instead of matching rows and multiplying, I want to match a column's values from df1 with a column name in df2 and return the corresponding row values of df2 in a new df3.

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=c(1:6),V2=c("X3", "X3_8", "NA", "X5", "X4_5", "X3_8"))
df1
    V1 V2
  1 1  X3
  2 2  X3_8
  3 3  NA
  4 4  X5
  5 5  X4_5
  6 6  X3_8

df2 <- data.frame(name=c("John", "Mary", "Joe", "Tim", "Bob", "Pat"),
                  X3=c(0.5, 1.2, 0.75, 3.1, 2.0, 1.1),
                  X5=c(1.0, 2.3, 4.2, 5, 1.1, 3.0),
                  X3_8=c(0.6, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.7, 1.4),
                  X4_5=c(0.4, 0.3, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.9))
df2
     name   X3    X5    X3_8  X4_5
  1  John   0.5   1.0   0.6   0.4
  2  Mary   1.2   2.3   1.0   0.3
  3  Joe    0.75  4.2   2.0   3.0
  4  Tim    3.1   5.0   1.0   1.0
  5  Bob    2.0   1.1   0.7   2.0
  6  Pat    1.1   3.0   1.4   0.9
```

This is what I want:

```
df3 <- data.frame(name=c("John", "Mary", "Joe", "Tim", "Bob", "Pat"),
                  values=c(0.5, 1.0, NA, 5.0, 1.0, 1.4))
    name values
  1 John    0.5
  2 Mary    1.0
  3  Joe     NA
  4  Tim    5.0
  5  Bob    1.0
  6  Pat    1.4
```

In my real df1 and df2 there are 64 rows, where "V1" in df1 corresponds to a numeric index for the "name" column in df2. In my df2, there are 22 columns, i.e., one with "name" and another 21 with "X*" to match "V2" in df1. I tried converting "V2" to row names, but this doesn't work because there are NA's and repeating values.

Bonus but not necessary: I have 10 df1s and 10 df2s and need to do this for each pair of df1s and df2s where the names of the df1s and the df2s contain common years. For example, I need to match df1_2004 with df2_2004, create df3_2004, and move on to df1_2005 and df2_2005, and so on. I'm sure there's an elegant way to do this without a for loop and an if statement.

Thanks for any assistance. I'm sure there's a simple base R or tidyrverse solution to this, but I'm struggling to put the pieces together. Forgive my newbie understanding of indexing in R.

Comment: In your desired solution,   shouldn't row 5, Bob, have a 2.0,  not 1.0?

Comment: @G5W Good catch. Yes, it should be 2.0 instead of 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a combination of reshaping `df2` into long format and a left join with `df1` you can get the desired result.

Using:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df3 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(name = df2$name[V1]) %>%  # or just mutate(name = df2$name) when the index is equal to the rownumbers
  left_join(., df2 %>% 
              gather(V2, values, -1) %>% 
              group_by(V2) %>% 
              mutate(V1 = row_number()), 
            by = c('V2','V1')) %>% 
  select(name = name.x, values)
```

gives:

> ```
> > df3
>   name values
> 1 John    0.5
> 2 Mary    1.0
> 3  Joe     NA
> 4  Tim    5.0
> 5  Bob    2.0
> 6  Pat    1.4
> ```

Comment: This works great! Two notes: (1) With my real data I had to index df2$name[1:64] in the first mutate call; (2) I changed "name.x" to "name" in the select function because it couldn't find "name.x". I suppose both of these are associated with nuances in my real data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The less functional procedure of the world:

```
n_row <- nrow(df1)
# corce the variable V1 in a factor with the name variables of the
# df2
df1$V1 <- factor(df1$V1, labels = df2$name)
# coerce the variable V2 into a character vector or use 'stringsAsFactors = FALSE' 
# when you read the data frame
df1$V2 <- as.character(df1$V2)
# create a copy of df1 to impute values of the V2 col
df3 <- df1
for (i in 1:n_row) {
  col_index <- which(df1[i, "V2"] == names(df2), arr.ind = TRUE)
  row_index <- which(df1[i, "V1"] == df2$name, arr.ind = TRUE)
  if (length(col_index) == 0) {
    df3[i, "V2"] <- NA
  } else {
    df3[i, "V2"] <- df2[row_index, col_index]
  }
}
names(df3) <- c("name", "values")
```

gives:

```
#>df3
   name  values
 1 John  0.5
 2 Mary    1
 3  Joe <NA>
 4  Tim    5
 5  Bob    2
 6  Pat  1.4
```

Comment: This also works, but Jaap's answer was closer to what I was looking for. Thanks.